# WebStorm creates duplicate files CSCC

Tags: javascript, webstorm

When I create a file `[name].scss`, WebStorm creates 2 more files for me inside `[name].css` and `[name].css.map`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can disable automatic compiling of scss files.

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on what plugin you are using that does this.

Comment: I did not connect plugins, if only there are some standard ones

Comment: you must have a SCSS file watcher configured. Check **Settings | Tools | File Watchers**

Comment: Lena, add your version to the answers. It's work, thanks!